# how to decrypt sqlite database android using sqlcipher?

Tags: android, sqlcipher

I need a local database for my application.I created one and i encrypted it.(I know the pw).Now i want to load this db to my original application's assets folder.I want to decrypt it before copy.
I had a copy code like this this is working for unencrpyted db.
How can I translate this for my encrypted db.Thanks

```
private void copyDataBase() throws IOException {

    //Open your local db as the input stream
    InputStream myInput = myContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);

    // Path to the just created empty db
    String outFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;

    //Open the empty db as the output stream
    OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

    //transfer bytes from the inputfile to the outputfile
    byte[] buffer = new byte[5120];
    int length;
    while ((length = myInput.read(buffer)) > 0) {
        myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
    }

    //Close the streams
    myOutput.flush();
    myOutput.close();
    myInput.close();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The proper way to do this would be to copy the encrypted database into a local folder. Then you can open it with SQLCipher and use [sqlcipher_export()](https://www.zetetic.net/sqlcipher/sqlcipher-api/#sqlcipher_export) to convert it into a standard (non-encrypted) SQLite database.

Comment: thank you for your answer.I figured it out and implemented to my project, I have x86,armeabi,armeabi7 folders now i am working to decrease app size because sqlcipher increased my apk size 8mb.